# C# IsolatedStorage problems

Tags: c#, windows-phone, isolatedstorage

I am currently developing a game for Windows Phone using C# XNA. Unfortunately, XNA's Storage is not supported on Windows Phone so I have to use C# IsolatedStorage, which I am not very familiar with. I am trying to make a player high score, where if the players score is higher than the last high score the program writes the score to a file stored on the device and every time the player opens the game, their high score is loaded from the file and shown to them.
The game seems to work fine, it tells the player that they have beaten their last high score but when I exit the game and run it again, the high score is displayed as zero. This bug has been killing me. I have tried everything so my last resort is to get on here.

Here is the class that deals with the storage:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO.IsolatedStorage;
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;

namespace Square_Eyes
{
    class RRSaveScore
    {
        public string highScoreConverted;
        public int highScore;

        public RRSaveScore() 
        {
            highScoreConverted = highScore.ToString();
        }

        public void WriteScore(RRScore score, GameTime gameTime)
        {
             IsolatedStorageFile fileStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();

             StreamWriter fileWriter = new StreamWriter
            (new IsolatedStorageFileStream("newText.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate,fileStorage));

            highScore = score.score;
            fileWriter.WriteLine(highScore.ToString());
            fileWriter.Close();
        }

         public void ReadScore()
         {
             IsolatedStorageFile fileStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
                StreamReader fileReader = null;
            try
            {
                fileReader = new StreamReader(new IsolatedStorageFileStream
                     ("newText.txt", FileMode.Open, fileStorage));

                highScoreConverted = fileReader.ReadLine();
                fileReader.Close();
            }
            catch
            {
                highScoreConverted = "0";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is what happens in the main game class:

```
     if (score.score > saveScore.highScore)
     {
           saveScore.WriteScore(score, gameTime);
           saveScore.ReadScore();
     }
```

Here is the draw method:

```
spriteBatch.DrawString(font, saveScore.highScoreConverted, new Vector2(100, 100), Color.White);
```

I NEED to get this done, any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Don't silently "catch". Instead, catch the exception and report it. Perhaps there's another error going on that you need to fix. EDIT: Also, have you debugged it to double-check that when you write, the _actual_ value of `highScore` is _not_ `0`?

Comment: Can you add what actually the problem is you have? So you can come up with a better title. And if you do, remove the c# tag from it...

Comment: This is a perfect example case for the free DLL I wrote called EZ_iso. It allows single line Isolated Storage calls. I am currently on Version 3 and working on pushing out version 4 this weekend. I just need to update the documentation then I can release it. You will find the DLL, the Documentation and the Source Code Here if you're interested in doing Isolated Storage the easy way lol http://www.anthonyrussell.info/postpage.php?name=2

Comment: Hello Anthony, that sounds great. I would love to try it but my firewall is blocking that website and I can't get in. Could you link the download on dropbox or something? Thanks.